# How do I refactor duplicate control structures?

Tags: c++, refactoring, c++14

I have duplicated control structures which are exactly the same, and the difference is how things happen inside. In particular, I don’t know how to deal with `break`, `continue`, and `return`. For example:

```
int f() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      if (isFoo(i, j)) {
        // doSomethingF1
      } else {
        // doSomethingF2
      }
    }
  }
}

int g() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      if (isFoo(i, j)) {
        // doSomethingG1
      } else {
        // doSomethingG2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where `doSomething`s rely on `i` and `j`, and need to `break` or `continue` through the `j` loop, and `return` out of the function. How do I factor this out to get rid of the duplication?

I thought of writing a function that would take the `doSomething`s as arguments, but I'm not sure how to deal with the `break`s, `continue`s, or `return`s.

*[I'm not fine with the duplication since there are some checks on `i` and `j` in `f()`, `g()`, and like four other functions that are exactly the same; the only difference is a few lines of code.]*

Comment: @drescherjm I accidentally pressed submit when I wasn't finished writing the question yet. Oops!

Comment: Take a template or an `std::function` parameter pair that you call in the body of the loop in the `if`/`else` blocks.

Comment: overuse of `break` and `continue` is just as good as `goto`. Use a while loop when the break condition is anything more compilcated than: "iterate from a to b"

Comment: btw you added some code, but there is still no `continue` or `break` in your example ;)

Comment: how to refactor the code depends on the part you dont show

Comment: Not sure what's unclear here...  avoiding duplication of control structures is a valid question (with non-obvious answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want/insist to have the same inner control in the loop context with `break`, `continue`, and `return` then the proposed solution is **macros** :-(.

On the other hand, if the `doSomethingFG12` functions all have a defined interface, then compliment your generic control structure to handle the case with `break`, `continue`, and `return` to make a choice from there return values.

Comment: Right, I can handle those cases with return values. Thanks.